# LDAP on openSUSE

Tags: opensuse, authentication, ldap

I'm trying to run an LDAP server on a openSUSE 12. But I have a couple of doubts.

What I whant is this: *testing.com* with 2 OU (*Info* and *People* ). So the right way would be `ou=Info,dc=testing,dc=com`.

I use this http://www.padl.com/OSS/MigrationTools.html to generate a ldif file named user `user_ldap.ldif`, with a few users (this is an example =D). After I edit the `migrate_common.ph` I create the `user_lda.ldif` file

```
 ~ # cat user_ldap.ldif 
dn: uid=inxs,ou=People,dc=testing,dc=com
uid: inxs
cn: INXS
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword: {crypt}$1$yQbmUggV$fNUvBGuOXru0DHQjtlu9h1
shadowLastChange: 15392
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1001
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/inxs
gecos: INXS

dn: uid=nofx,ou=People,dc=testing,dc=com
uid: nofx
cn: NOFX
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword: {crypt}$1$vxU/f4tt$LRHuHhLgPhqcGVA2yLUKk/
shadowLastChange: 15392
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1002
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/nofx
gecos: NOFX
```

So I try to do this:

```
:~ # ldapadd -f user_ldap.ldif 
SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication started
Please enter your password: 
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
        additional info: SASL(-13): user not found: no secret in database
```

When I installed the ldap-server, I created the `dn=root` with his password, so I asumed that is the password that this asking.

I do not create the directory tree I was told that was created automatically from the ldapadd. Or it's false?

I have a lot to learn, but need a guide or a small synthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want insert this records to the ldap, you must use this command:

```
ldapadd -D 'whole dn of root' -f user_ldap.ldif
```

for example:

```
ldapadd -D 'cn=root,dc=testing,dc=com' -f user_ldap.ldif
```

Then you will be asking for password, which you set for LDAP root dn. But please: I don't know, which is your root dn, use your own.

EDIT: You have to add basic entries:

```
dn: dc=testing,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: testing.com organization
dc: testing
structuralObjectClass: organization

dn: ou=People,dc=testing,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People
ou: People of testing.com organization
structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit
```

Note: When will `ldapadd` complain, try to remove both `structuralObjectClass` lines.

For explaining: LDAP want to have defined whole path from 'root' (which is your organization `dc=testing,dc=com`) to the `leafs`, which are in this case some users on `ou=People` 'branch'. If you would like to have in LDAP machines and they will have `ou=Machines` 'organizational unit', you must add to the LDAP directory 'branch' `ou=Machines` (like `ou=People`, but only substitute word 'People' with word 'Machines' in my sample) and then you can add 'leafs' - entries for machines.

Comment: ldap-dind: Server is unwiling to perform (53) now I see that I another issues about the configuration.. hehe thanx anyway...

Comment: @maniat1k Try to add `-x` option to the `ldapadd` command. Or you may have not included some schemas in the slapd.conf (or in the `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/` directory)...

Comment: @maniat1k Have you added entries for dc=testing,dc=com and for ou=People? See my updated answer...

Comment: No actually I don't,  asumed that the ldif file will do that. Actually later on will continu with the test. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly binding as dn=root?

Comment: please ad more info, show me an example... you mean `ldapadd "dn=root" -f user_ldap.ldif` ?

Comment: No - the answer below spells it out.